# Как продолжить выполнять код после функции?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть функция, в которой выводится нужное мне значение, это значение нужно потом отправить в телеграм, но ниже строчки с вызовом функции питон как будто ничего не видит.

```
class Checher:
    def __init__(self, url,count_vins):
        self.url = url
        self.count_vins = count_vins

    def firefox_work(self):
        options = Options()
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
        options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
        options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
        options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        browser.get(self.url)
        global n
        n = 0
        while n != max:

            time.sleep(3)
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                 "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/input").send_keys("")
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                 "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/input").send_keys(lines[n])
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                 "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/input").click()
            if len(browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "vin-check__card-items")) != 0:
                print(lines[n])
                global m
                m = n
                browser.save_screenshot(f"humver {n}.png")

            n += 1
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/input").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "BACKSPACE")

        

bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
async def on_start(_):
    print("Бот запущен")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Привет, проверка запущена")
    pars1 = Checher("https://customs.gov.ru/cars", 1)
    
    pars1.firefox_work() вывод этой функции должен обрабатываться и выводиться
```

Comment: А чему у вас равно `max`? И почему вы думаете, что ничего не работает? Пока вы не добавите логирование везде по коду, вы не сможете понять, какие строки кода у вас работают, а какие нет.

Comment: я смотрел, всё что ниже pars1.firefox_work() не обрабатывается